# I'm trying to create an Instagram bot in Python3 for practice for Web Scraping (Error of no module found)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create a program in Python3 that will be able to access Instagram. I'm using `selenium`, installed by writing in terminal `pip3 install selenium`. I'm also using Chrome Driver. I've downloaded selenium, but when I run the program I get this:

```
File "instagrambot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")

InstaBot()
```

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: MacOs  (currently Catalina)

Comment: Did you try running the install with sudo? (`sudo pip3 install selenium`)

Comment: I just tried it, but it didn't even download, it simply gave me many errors

Comment: What are those errors?

Comment: Now, I tried to download normally and it gave me the same errors as before, now I don't know what happened

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us the errors